# zero pading the end of list in multiples of random number in c#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

Hello I have a list looks like that:

```
List<float> myList = new List<float>();
```

I fill the list with a numbers(a samples that come from a micrphone). The Count number in the end is unknown.

I run on the list with a for loop in jumps of 8820(This number can be changed, let call it X).
But sometimes I get an exception that my index of loop is out of bounds. I have to pad the end of the list with zeros such that the whole list will be in muliplies of 8820(X).

Is there any efficient way to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your loop?

Comment: why can't you just break out of the loop when you reach the end of the list?

Comment: Try using the modulus operator and `.Count()` function to determine how many times you need to iterate through your loop.

Comment: Also, what does "The Count number in the end is unknown." mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the loop when you are reaching the list count!

Or you can just add at the end some zeroes to the list like this:

```
int X=8820;
for (int i = 0; i < X - (myList.Count / X); i++)
    myList.Add(0f);
```

Comment: Thanks, breaking the loop helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Declare and initialize variables
List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
Random r = new Random();
int LoopJumps = r.Next(2,30);
MyList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, r.Next(1, 100));

// the loop code
for(int i=0; i < MyList.Count; i+= LoopJumps) {
    if(i >= MyList.Count) break;
    // Do your thing...
}
```